# Please help to optimize simple JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

**I have a such functions for jQuery:**

```
$("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
$("input").blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});

$("select").focus(function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
$("select").blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});

$("textarea").focus(function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
$("textarea").blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
```

**Is it possible to optimize, for a less code?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("input,select,textarea").focus(function() {$(this).toggleClass('focus')})
                          .blur(function() {$(this).toggleClass('focus')});
```

or

```
$("input,select,textarea").bind('focus blur',function() {$(this).toggleClass('focus')});
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a new for this excelent site, the answer is accepted now.

Comment: The problem with this code is, it will work correctly only if no other script modifies the class names. If there is another script, that will remove the focus class while textarea is in focus, the blur handler will add the class again. Yeah, this situation won't probably occur in 99.9% of cases, but still may occur for the 0.1%, thus using toggleClass isn't the best way to do it. This can be fixed by changing the function to $("input,select,textarea").bind('focus blur',function (event) { $(this).toggleClass('focus', event && event.type === 'focus');})

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
$("input, textarea, select").focus(function () {
   $(this).addClass('focus');
}).blur(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
```